What is a general parameterization of the real 3-sphere?
In $\mathbb{R}^2$, the unit circle can be parameterized as
$$
\cos \theta \vec{x}_1 + 
\sin \theta \vec{x}_2,
$$
where $\vec{x}_1$ and $\vec{x}_2$ are orthonormal vectors. Given two vectors $\vec{v}_1, \vec{v}_2 \in \mathbb{C}^2$, what is a parameterization of the values $\lambda_1, \lambda_2 \in \mathbb{C}$ in terms of real quantities that give all solutions to
$$
(\lambda_1^* \vec{v}_1^H + \lambda_2^* \vec{v}_2^H) (\lambda_1 \vec{v}_1 + \lambda_2 \vec{v}_2) = 1,
$$
where $\vec{y}^H$ is the conjugate transpose of $\vec{y}$ and $z^*$ is the complex conjugate of $z$?
My best guess so far has been $\lambda_1 = \cos \frac{\theta}{2},\hspace{0.1cm} \lambda_2 = e^{i\phi} \sin \frac{\theta}{2}$, which satisfies the condition above, but since $\lambda_1$ is restricted to the reals, some solutions are not covered by this parameterization.

To confirm, are you asking, in essence: Given two orthogonal unit vectors $v_1$ and $v_2$ in the complex Cartesian plane $\mathbf{C}^{2}$ equipped with the standard Hermitian inner product, how can we describe all complex scalars $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ such that $|\lambda_1 v_{1} + \lambda_2 v_{2}| = 1$? That is, the stated vectors are "orthonormal" and you're trying to describe the real $3$-sphere (not the complex unit circle)? <> Separately, "geometry" looks like a more accurate tag than "complex geometry", though it may depend on your motivation for asking.

That is correct. I made the changes to the title and tags as you suggested, thanks.

The real 3-sphere, denoted $S^3$, is a 3-dimensional manifold, so you are going to need 3 coordinates. But there is no single set of 3 coordinates which covers the whole of $S^3$. This is somewhat like $S^2$, where there is no single set of $2$ coordinates which covers the whole of $S^2$. We sometimes use "spherical" $r,\theta,\phi$ coordinates for $\mathbb R^3$ and then set $r=1$ to get $\theta,\phi$ coordinates for $S^2$, but those break down at the north and south poles.

Similarly any set of $3$ coordinates for $S^3$ is either not going to cover, or its going to break down at some points.

Let's first assume the vectors are $e_{1} = (1, 0)$ and $e_{2} = (0, 1)$. The desired set of scalars is the set of pairs $(\lambda_{1}, \lambda_{2})$ satisfying
$$
|(\lambda_{1}, \lambda_{2})|^{2} = |\lambda_{1}^{2} + |\lambda_{2}|^{2} = 1,
$$
namely the $3$-sphere itself interpreted as a subset of the (complex Cartesian) $(\lambda_{1}, \lambda_{2})$-plane. This set requires three real parameters to describe. One possible choice, letting $\theta_{1}$, $\theta_{2}$, and $\phi$ be real is
$$
\lambda_{1} = \cos\phi\, e^{i\theta_{1}},\qquad
\lambda_{2} = \sin\phi\, e^{i\theta_{2}}.
$$
To see why this suffices, write each $\lambda_{j} = r_{j}e^{i\theta_{j}}$ in polar form, and note that
$$
1 = |(\lambda_{1}, \lambda_{2})|^{2} = r_{1}^{2} + r_{2}^{2},
$$
so there exists a real $\phi$ such that $r_{1} = \cos\phi$ and $r_{2} = \sin\phi$.
To get "complete coverage with overlap only at the boundary," let each parameter range over an interval of length $2\pi$. If it matters, there is no "nice parametrization covering the entire sphere," i.e., no covering map from Cartesian three-space to the $3$-sphere in the sense of topology. The mapping above wraps the $(\theta_{1}, \theta_{2})$-plane (really, each of the planes $\phi = \text{constant}$) around real $2$-tori; these tori collapse to circles where $\cos\phi = 0$ (first factor of $S^{1} \times S^{1}$ collapses) or $\sin\phi = 0$ (second factor collapses).
<>
Now suppose $v_{1}$ and $v_{2}$ are arbitrary orthogonal unit vectors. There exists a unique unitary transformation (complex-linear in particular) taking $(e_{1}, e_{2})$ to $(v_{1}, v_{2})$; that is, there exists a unique $2 \times 2$ unitary matrix $A$ satisfying $v_{j} = Ae_{j}$ for $j = 1$, $2$. Multiplication by $A$ maps the $3$-sphere bijectively to itself, and
$$
A(\lambda_{1}e_{1} + \lambda_{2}e_{2})
= \lambda_{1}\, Ae_{1} + \lambda_{2}\, Ae_{2}
= \lambda_{1} v_{1} + \lambda_{2} v_{2},
$$
so the same scalars "work" for the arbitrary basis.
